# Bookmarking of FireFox tab groups

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I use FireFox tab groups a lot. Most of my tab groups need to persist indefinitely or for a good length of time. I already have "show my windows and tabs from last time" option enabled, but I periodically loose my tab groups via the following pattern:

1. Have my main window (with tab groups) open.
2. Open another window for whatever purpose.
3. Close the main window without first closing the extra window.

Bam. All the work in setting up tab groups is gone. Very frustrating as tab groups is otherwise a very useful feature.

What I'd like is a way to create a super bookmark that represents not a single page but a set of tab groups, ideally preserving tab arrangement, groups position/size on canvas, group names, etc. in addition to the URLs of the actual pages.

Anyone know of such an addin?

Answer (score 2):

[Tabgroups manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabgroups-manager/) seems to do something like that.

Comment: The Tabgroups Manager addon appears to be a solution for grouping tabs for FireFox 3.x, before FireFox had built-in tab groups. This doesn't solve the issue that I have.